# How to subset data in SAS

Tags: sas, subset

```
     Variable       ParameterEstimate
     slope                  1
     intercept             2.5
     slope                  2
     intercept             5.6
     slope                22.2
     intercept              9
```

Suppose my dataset looks something like this, where the variable names are `Variable` and `ParameterEstimate`. I want to extract just the ParameterEstimates of the slope. However, I can't think of a simple way to do that. How can I go about getting just the slopes, i.e just 1, 2, and 22.2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subsetting where clause like this:

```
data want;
set have;
where variable = 'slope';
run;
```

This reads only those observations from data set "have" where the value of variable equals 'slope'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing with it next, you can probably do this without a separate datastep.

Say you wanted the mean of the slopes:

```
proc means data=have(where=(variable='slope'));
var parameterEstimate;
run;
```

In most cases you can use a `where` data set option, unless you have reason to create a new dataset (perhaps you're going to use this subset for 50 different steps or somesuch where it's easier to create one than to type that bit out 50 times).